# Count the number of words in a string by using a dictionary using a csv file in Python

Tags: python, string, csv, dictionary, count

I have a code where it returns a dictionary from a csv file. With this I would like to count the number of words are in any string. For instance, if I input:

"How many words in this string are from dict1"

How would I loop through this string and count the words from dict1 that appear in the string?

**Code:**

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename, col_list):
"""This function expects the name of a CSV file and a list of strings
representing a subset of the headers of the columns in the file, and
returns a dictionary of the data in those columns."""

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # Better covert reader to a list (items represent every row)
        reader = list(csv.DictReader(f))
        dict1 = {}
        for col in col_list:
            dict1[col] = []
            # Going in every row of the file
            for row in reader:
                # Append to the list the row item of this key
                dict1[col].append(row[col])

    return dict1
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
str_ = "How many words in this string are from dict1"
dict_1 = dict(a='many', b='words')

# With list comprehension

len([x for x in str_.split() if x in dict_1.values()])
# 2

# These ones don't count duplicates because they use sets

len(set(str_.split()).intersection(dict_1.values()))
# 2
len(set(str_.split()) & set(dict_1.values()))  # Equivalent, but different syntax
# 2

# To be case insensitive, do e.g.,
words = str_.lower().split()
dict_words = map(str.lower, dict_1.values())
```

Comment: dict_1 and the string cannot be previously defined, they have to be able to be inputed.

Comment: OK, so rewrite the code as a function: `def matches(dict_, str_): ...`